# Tensorflow inception final layer bazel retain error

Tags: python-2.7, build, tensorflow, neural-network, bazel

following [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)  in Tensorflow site;
i am trying to retrain inception model final layer in Ubuntu+python 2.7 environment.when running below command

> $ bazel build /home/incept/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain

it gives an error.
ERROR: not a valid absolute pattern (absolute target patterns must start with exactly two slashes)
[image]

any suggestion to fix this? example mention try

> $ bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain

Comment: `cd /home/incept/tensorflow/; bazel build //tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain`

Comment: @AllenLavoie that *is* the answer, please promote it ;)

Comment: Thank you.@Allen Lavoie ..but it gives an error for me ..**root@test-virtual-machine:/home/incept/models# bazel build //tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain**
.....................................................
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining': BUILD file not found on package path.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.745s'

Comment: @Lanka you're in `/home/incept/models` rather than `/home/incept/tensorflow/`

Comment: @AllenLavoie sorry for that mistake.it gives below error;         
 root@test-virtual-machine:/home/incept/tensorflow# bazel build //tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
.........................................................
ERROR: /home/incept/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1394:1: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/spec.json': target 'gen/spec.json' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by /home/incept/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'.

Comment: Guess one would be that you need to run `./configure` first. Guess two would be an old/broken build, in which case `git pull` may fix it. Guess three is an older Bazel version. So if `git pull` and `./configure` doesn't fix it, please edit in the output of `git show -s` and `bazel version`.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thank you.thats the answer.it's success in the first step. Target //tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain up-to-date: done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize general TensorFlow build issue debugging (on Linux) in case other people end up here with similar issues:

- Make sure you're in the directory you checked out. So if `git clone` made you a `tensorflow` directory, `bazel` commands should be run in that directory tree. It doesn't matter where in the tree if the build target is absolute (`//tensorflow/...`).
- Run `./configure` in the `tensorflow` directory. This fetches necessary dependencies in addition to allowing you to configure the build (you can `yes "" | ./configure` if you don't want to bother answering the questions and just want the defaults).
- Make sure you have the latest version of [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) and a compatible Java installation.
- The git repository changes quite a bit. `git pull` will get you the latest (`git checkout` can get you any version you'd like).